# my code for touchSwipe causing TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, touch, typeerror

Trying to use touchSwipe - TouchSwipe: http://labs.skinkers.com/touchSwipe/

When the page loads, I get the following error (in firebug):

```
TypeError: $(...).swipe is not a function

swipe: function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
```

The code is

```
$(function() {
    $('#showdivrightcover').swipe({
        swipe: function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
            if (direction=='left') {
                $('#showdivrightcover').trigger('click');
            } 
        }
})  
});
```

Can't figure out what I'm doing to cause the error - thanks for any help.

Comment: It seems an inclusion error. Did you included in the correct order both jquery and touchswipe?

Comment: I think so, jquery first then touchswipe.

Comment: I can't figure out with those infos, can you set online the entire page, so I can check it?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at it. It turns out it was caused by loading two js scripts with many identical function names. The code above works fine now.